# Evaluate LogLevel of configured logproviders

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core-2.0

I have the requirement to log requests/responses in an asp.net core 2.0 web application. For that we created a RequestLoggingMiddleware (see below).

This solution has the disadvantage that the bodystreams will be read each request. Is there a way to evaluate if there is a logprovider which is configured for a specific loglevel. For example in the case no logprovider is listening to the DebugLog-Level we need not to read the body stream.

```
public class RequestLoggingMiddleware
{
    public ILogger<RequestLoggingMiddleware> Logger { get; }
    public RequestDelegate NextMiddleware { get; }


    public RequestLoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate nextMiddleware, ILogger<RequestLoggingMiddleware> logger)
    {
        NextMiddleware = nextMiddleware;
        Logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        using (MemoryStream loggableResponseStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Logger.LogDebug(await FormatRequest(context.Request));

            await NextMiddleware(context);
        }
    }

    private static async Task<string> FormatRequest(HttpRequest request)
    {
        Stream body = request.Body;
        request.EnableRewind();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(request.ContentLength)];
        await request.Body.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        string bodyAsText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
        request.Body = body;

        var messageObjToLog = new
        {
            scheme = request.Scheme,
            host = request.Host,
            path = request.Path,
            queryString = request.Query,
            requestBody = bodyAsText
        };

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(messageObjToLog);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ILogger` interface has `IsEnabled` method defined as:

```
bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel);
```

> Is there a way to evaluate if there is a logprovider which is
> configured for a specific loglevel.

Default implementation of `ILogger` keeps a collection of configured loggers. And implementation of `IsEnabled` method works exactly as you described: all loggers are enumerated and `true` is returned if at least one of the loggers has specified log level enabled.

[Logger Source code on github](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/Logger.cs)

So the following check should do the job for you:

```
if (logger.IsEnabled(LogLevel.Debug))
{
    //  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This work with each logprovider for example with NLOG?

Comment: It should work for properly implemented loggers. However I haven't tried it with NLog specifically.